# Overriding values c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection

I have a situation where in I have 3 `classes` like below:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int DepID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int DepID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}  

public class C
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

From the above `classes` we see that there are few common properties b/w 3 `classes`.

I have a situation where I have to create a final output by combining the values from 3 `classes` and overriding them when there and values in lower `classes`.

For ex:-

Consider property Age which is all 3 `classes` `A`, `B` and `C` but if the value of it in `C` is not `null` while merging the value in `class` `C` takes priority, and this will be the case for all the properties.

I have already achieved this using **`Reflection`**, by reading the values from the instance of all the 3 `classes` I have by using `.GetType()` and `.GetProperties()` methods which are part of `System.Reflection` library.

With the current `Reflection based` approach I will able to handle any addition of properties in any of the `classes`.

But I have read that the `Reflection` is bad on performance.

So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You need to look at inheritance. Put the common properties in base class and derive the other class(es) from that.

Comment: This question is about software dessign patterns, isn't it?

Comment: This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at inheritance. Your data structure should look like this:

```
public class C
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : C
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int DepID { get; set; }
}  

public class A : B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
}
```

You just create objects of the right type, and each has the properties it needs, but you don't get duplicate properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance to push the common properties down to a base class, and then derive from them to create the others, e.g.:

```
public class A : B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
}

public class B : C
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int DepID { get; set; }
}  

public class C
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can be used to identify groups of properties. This approach does not force you to change established class hierarchy.

```
 interface IData1
 {
     int Id { get;set; }
     int BranchId { get;set; }
 }

 interface IData2 
 {
     int LocationId { get;set; }
     int DepID { get;set; }
 }

 interface IData3
 {
      int Age { get;set; }
      string Name { get;set; }
 }


 public class A : IData1, IData2, IData3
 {
      public int Id { get;set; }
      public int BranchId { get;set; }
      public int LocationId { get;set; }
      public int DepID { get;set; }
      public int Age { get;set; }
      public string Name { get;set; }
 }

 public class B : IData2, IData3
 {
     public int LocationId { get;set; }
     public int DepID { get;set; }
     public int Age { get;set; }
     public string Name { get;set; }
 }

 public class C : IData3
 {
     public int Age { get;set; }
     public string Name { get;set; }
  }

 void WriteData1(IData1 data){}
 void WriteData2(IData2 data){}
 void WriteData3(IData3 data){}

 void WriteProperties(A a, B b, C c)
 {
       WriteData1(a);

       WriteData2(a);
       WriteData2(b);

       WriteData3(a);
       WriteData3(b);
       WriteData3(c); 
  }
```